# Wrong value in cell after search

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm new in Objective C, and here is my problem. I have array of two values, 
int & string:

```
[Messier new:1 :@"Name 1"],
[Messier new:2 :@"Name 2"]...
```

I pushed these array in my tableView, in tableView a have UISearchBar. When i tap cell i create Text button "Show"

[image]

i need to return from my array int value of selected Name(name in cell). In normal state(before searching) my button returns me right value, but after searching returns wrong. For example(look on picture above) Andromeda have number 11, Butterfly 20, Beehive 30, I'm searching for Beehive(numb 30), after search(Beehive get first cell) i get value 11(it's Andromeda value), not 30 as i need.

Here is my serchBar code:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if([searchText isEqualToString:@""] || searchText == Nil)
    {
        searching = NO;
    }
    else
    {

        searching = YES;

        [searchArray removeAllObjects];

        searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        searchDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        NSArray *sourceArray;
        NSDictionary *sourceDictionary;

        sourceArray = [[AstroData sharedAstroData] messierObjectsArray];
        sourceDictionary = [[AstroData sharedAstroData] messierNameIndexesDictionarry];

        for(NSString *key in [sourceDictionary allKeys])
        {
            NSArray *messier = [sourceDictionary objectForKey:key];
            for(Messier *mess in messier)
            {
                NSRange result = [mess.name rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];
                if(result.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    NSMutableArray *existingArray;
                    if((existingArray = [searchDictionary objectForKey:key]))
                    {
                        [existingArray addObject:mess];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
                        [searchDictionary setObject:tempArray forKey:key];
                        [tempArray addObject:mess];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for(id key in sourceArray)
        {
            if([searchDictionary objectForKey:key])
                [searchArray addObject:key];
        }
    }
    [table reloadAllComponents];
}
```

Maybe i have a problem with table view? Thank to all.

P.S. Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in Text button "Show", all i need is to add in but method

```
if(search)
....
else
... but code
```